# Trying to find three (exactly) consecutive copies of whatever text is contained in whatever variable

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string

Homework issue. Perhaps I'm not understanding the question:
RegEx - three consecutive copies of whatever text is contained in the *whatever* variable.

I've tried this:
in the variable *whatever*, I have tried 2 copies and 4 copies. Both of these **correctly return false.** But the 3 copy version also returns **false** when it **should be true.**

`whatever = "blahblahblah"

re.search("blah{3}", whatever)`

I'm pretty sure this is the way I need to go, but RegEx is required.

**Clarification**
It needs to be set up as such:
`whatever = "blah"
re.search(whatever{3}, "blahblahblah")`
That is, the re.search needs to use the variable *whatever* for the text pattern to search in a given string. I hope this makes more sense. I'm still working on it.
re.search(*whatever*{3}, "blahblahblah") <-- syntax error 
re.search(*whatever*, "blahblahblah") <-- works, but only for variable once.

I'm unsure of the syntax to look for the variable (value) to be there 3 times.

**EDIT**
whatever = "blah"
re.search(*whatever*{2}, "blahblahblahblah") comes back true
Also {2,2} does not work. Those are my best guesses thus far.

Comment: `blah{3}` matches `blahhh` Do you mean `(?:blah){3}`

Comment: Yes, I need to confirm three consecutive copies of any text. So 2 and 4 copies should return false. I had considered the "blahhh" error, but tried [blah]{3} to no avail (syntax error)

Answer (score 2):

From your updated post, it seems you want to match any word as contained in a variable, **exactly** **three** times and otherwise should fail the match if that variable is appearing either once or twice or four times or five times or any larger number of times.

Let your variable word be `blah` then you need to use this regex,

```
(?<!blah)(?:blah){3}(?!blah)
```

Here `(?:blah){3}` will match `blah` exactly three times and this `(?<!blah)` negative look behind will fail the match if matched word is preceded by `blah` and this `(?!blah)` negative look ahead will fail the match if `blah` is followed by the match.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/njgr67/1)**

Here is a Python code,

```
import re

arr = ['aablahaa','aablahblahaa','aablahblahblahaa','aablahblahblahblahaa','aablahblahblahblahblahaa']

whatever = "blah"
reg = r"(?<!{})(?:{}){}(?!{})".format(whatever,whatever,'{3}',whatever) # construct regex dynamically using whatever word

for s in arr:
 if re.search(reg, s):
  print(s, '-->', 'Matched')
 else:
  print(s, '-->', "Didn't Matched")
```

Prints this, where it shows only string is matched which contains `blah` exactly three times and rest all failed.

```
aablahaa --> Didn't Matched
aablahblahaa --> Didn't Matched
aablahblahblahaa --> Matched
aablahblahblahblahaa --> Didn't Matched
aablahblahblahblahblahaa --> Didn't Matched
```

Comment: This is a great start, but fails if there are 4 copies.

Comment: @SadieRose: If you want it to match at least three or more, then just change it to `(.+)\1{2,}` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yLfZEV/2)

Comment: Actually, that won't work. See my update above. Thank you

Comment: @SadieRose: Ok, I think your question is more clear now. Let me update my answer and see if that is what you were looking for. Now as I know, only and only three occurrence should match and for 2 or 4 it should fail to match.

Comment: So, looking at your code:  (.+)\1{2}, the (.+) should be matching the variable string.

Comment: @SadieRose: Check my updated answer. Let me know if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Brilliant way to work around! Thank you so much! And it works!

Comment: @SadieRose: Happy to know my answer solved your problem. Please consider upvoting and accepting my answer if it solved your problem and it will also give you +2 rep and help others in case they are looking for a solution to a problem similar to yours.